# How can I generate a list of spoken languages in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a `<select>` with a list of all language names in the world. And I want it available in all different languages as well.

I'm using Angular 8 and ngx-translate and haven't found a good library/way to do this, and Angulars built in language capability doesn't seem to support this.

For instance, if the current users language is English I want:

`<option>English</option>`

to appear in this list but if the current users language is Swedish I want:

`<option>Engelska</option>`.

Generating a list of **country** names is easy enough, but not **language** name, which I need. Yes, I've tried googling.

Comment: This issue has little to nothing to do w/ js/Angular.  Other than the question of native compatibility.  I suggest you ask for a software recommendation instead: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The root of the question could be clarified too.  Not all countries have a 1:1 relationship with a language.  And what about Klingon, Elvish or cultures with languages or vernacular that don't use computers?  I suspect there is something out there for you, but I think this is the wrong way to start looking.

Comment: Most libraries usually have the language name in English and then the native name. You will need to find an actively maintained library that supports this and maintains the list. This has nothing to do with angular and nothing with javascript either. It is a matter of finding a trusted source that contains this information. It might be a javascript library but it might also be some end point you have to pay for.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, besides Angular and ngx-translate, you will need a DB with two tables. At least that is how I managed to translate language names. This is example for MSSQL DB.

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Languages](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DateFormat] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Flag] [varbinary](max) NULL)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LanguagesNames](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDLanguages] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IDLanguages2] [int] NOT NULL)
```

In the Languages table you will have a list of all languages in a form:

```
    ID Code DateFormat Active Flag
    1  en   YYYY/MM/DD  1     <some charactes>
    2  de   DD.MM.YYYY  1     <some charactes>
```

In the LanguagesNames table you will have a list of all names of all languages and all translations:

```
ID IDLanguages Name     IDLanguages2
1    1         English   1
2    1         German    2
3    2         Englisch  1
4    2         Deutsche  2
```

You need to enter all languages in to the first table, and all the translations of all languages names in the second table. When you do that, the first step is finished.

**Call to DB:**

SQL call to DB looks like this:

```
SELECT l.ID, l.Code, l.Active, l.Flag, ln.Name 
FROM Languages l 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT IDLanguages2, Name FROM LanguagesNames
     WHERE IDLanguages = (Select ID from Languages where Code = @CODE) ) ln
ON l.ID = ln.IDLanguages2
AND l.Active = 1
```

Every time you change your language in a web app created with the Angular, you need to triger a call to a server. In that call you need to send a new language code, and get a list of all languages translated to a new selected language. The list you get, you can use in your select.

If you need any more help with setting ngx-translate or a services in the Angular to make this work, just let me know, and I will send you my Angular code with example how I did this.